# iPad compatability - 9.3.5

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some basic web app games for my kids to play. They have this old iPad:
3rd GEN
model MC707B/A
running version 9.3.5
Could someone help me out with how I make this code compatible please?..

The game is here:    games.lauraizzard.co.uk/MoanaMatch
and code is below.

It's working on other operating systems (within Chrome/Safari etc) but I need it so that they can use the touch screen function of the iPad!
Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Moana Matching Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" carset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title"><h1>Moana Matching Game</h1></div>
    <div class="score"><h2>Score:<span id="result"></span></h2></div>
    <div class="grid">
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
// fires when the initial HTML document has been loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

//intial card array
const cardArray = [
    {
        name: 'T1',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-1.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T1',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-1.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T2',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-2.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T2',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-2.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T3',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-3.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T3',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-3.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T4',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-4.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T4',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-4.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T5',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-5.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T5',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-5.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T6',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-6.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T6',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-6.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T7',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-7.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T7',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-7.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T8',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-8.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T8',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-8.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T9',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-9.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'T9',
        img: 'images/Moana-tile-9.jpg'
    }
]

//sort the card array randomly.
cardArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
console.log(cardArray);
    // arrow function returns anything on the right of the =>
    // default sorting is alphabetical unless you have something in the parentheses

//console.log(cardArray);

//select the html element 'grid' and define it as 'grid' in JS:
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
    
    //select the 'result' span in order to update text
    //const resultDisplay = document.querySelector('#result')

//setup 3 blank arrays:
var cardsChosen = []; 
var cardsChosenId = [];
var cardsWon = [];


//create game board
function createBoard() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
        //give each card an image elemet:
        var card = document.createElement('img');
        card.setAttribute('src', 'images/Moana-tile-BACK.jpg')
        //give each card an id number:
        card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
        //console.log(card);
        //run the function 'flipcard' when a card is clicked
        card.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        //console.log("CARD = " + card);
        
// WHAT DOES THIS DO ??   DELETE SOMETHING? RESET?
        grid.appendChild(card);
    }
}


//check for match
function checkForMatch() {
    //returns all image elements in the document:
    var cards = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    //console.log("CARDS = " + cards); //object NodeList
    
    //only need this next bit to turn them white:
    const optionOneId = cardsChosenId[0];
    const optionTwoId = cardsChosenId[1];
    //console.log("Cards Chosen IDs: " + cardsChosenId[0],cardsChosenId[1]);
    
    //checks if the image names are the same
    if (cardsChosen[0] === cardsChosen[1]) {
        alert('You found a match!');
    //makes selected images white:
        cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.jpg')
        cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.jpg')
        cardsWon.push(cardsChosen);
    } else {
        //turn them back over
        cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/Moana-tile-BACK.jpg');
        cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/Moana-tile-BACK.jpg');
        alert("Sorry, try again!")
    }
    // empty these arrays:
    cardsChosen = [];
    cardsChosenId = [];
    
    //print the score at the top of the page
    //resultDisplay.textContent = cardsWon.length;
    
    
    
    //once score matches half initial card array then game is over:
// THIS BIT ISN'T WORKING:
// MIGHT NEED TO BE IN A DIFFERENT PLACE?
    //console.log("cardsWon.length = " + cardsWon.length);
    //console.log("cardArray/2 = " + cardArray.length/2);
    //if (cardsWon.length === cardArray/2) {
        //resultDisplay.textContent = 'Congratulations! 100%';
    //}
}



//flip card
function flipCard() {
    // this line tells you which card you clicked on [0-17]:
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log("CARD ID = " + cardId);
    
    // push the ID of the chosen card into the array 'cardsChosen':
    cardsChosen.push(cardArray[cardId].name);
    //console.log("cardsChosen = " + cardsChosen);
    
    // push the DATA ID into the array:
    cardsChosenId.push(cardId);
        //console.log(cardsChosenId);    
        //console.log(cardArray);
    
    //add an image to the square based on the CARD ID it holds
    this.setAttribute('src', cardArray[cardId].img)
    
    console.log(cardsChosen.length);
    
    if (cardsChosen.length === 2) {
        // check for a match after 500ms:
        setTimeout(checkForMatch, 500)
    }
}

//run the create board function
createBoard();

})
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? If yes, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: the code works perfectly, just not compatible running on my iPad through safari.

Comment: If the code **works perfectly**, what's the question? What **exactly** is not working on your iPad then?

Answer (score 0):

The code is not working on iPad IOS 9.

You need to go through every line of code to see whether the older versions of Safari on IOS implement the statements you are using correctly. https://caniuse.com/ is useful for this.

One thing I have noticed is that this line:

```
cardArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
```

will not be recognised - and any further interpretation of the JS stops. The problem here is that the older versions of Safari (including for IOS) do not implement anonymous functions.

EDIT: when I mended that sort the rest seemed to work as well as on Edge on Windows10 so I was possibly being pessimistic saying every line needs inspection.

As an aside I have played around with implementing simple webapp games (on even older iPads) and if it helps have a look at http://ahweb.org.uk/games/ to see if any of the ideas or code are of interest. There is a contact address there if you would like to know more - and one of the games is a card matching one. It comes with a warning - some of the code is probably 10 years old, and some 'just worked' rather than me analysing why in depth.

Comment: Thank you so much - I'll have a look at this tomorrow. Don't worry - I'm the same with my projects! Get them done so that they 'work' and then move on to learn something new! That's why the design is so shocking in this one.